# ggplot is plotting all my data into a single line

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, r-plotly, ggplotly

I am making a dashboard that plots an x and y input. However when both inputs are passed, ggplot plots my data into a singular line. I have also tried using plotly and I get no result altogether.  Would someone be able to help with a working ggplot and plotly example.

here is the ggplot code portion plus image result

```r
renderPlot({
   p <- ggplot(Merged_data_frame_hcat, aes_string(x=input$x, y=input$y)) + geom_point()
 
   print(p)
  
})
```

[image]

and the plotly code plus image

```r
renderPlot({
  p <- plot_ly(data= Merged_data_frame_hcat,x= ~input$x, y= ~input$y,type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines' )
 
   print(p)
  
})
```

[image]

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. What exactly is in your data.frame? Are you sure you are passing correct column names to `aes_string()`

Comment: use `cat(input$x,'\n')` before plotting to debug your code : looks like it's equal to 1

Comment: Looks like whatever `input$x` is... it's possibly numeric.  Otherwise... well, it's equal to 1.

Comment: df <-data.frame("Timestamp.Excel_1900."=c("2019-04-01 16:52:51","2019-04-01 16:57:46","2019-04-01 17:02:51","2019-04-01 17:07:46","2019-04-01 17:12:52","2019-04-01 17:17:46"), "Temperature.C."= c(5.2995,5.3155,5.3353,5.3536,5.3770,5.4044))

Comment: Here are some of the values that I am trying to plot as a data frame. @Waldi I tried p <- ggplot(Merged_data_frame_hcat, aes_string(x=cat(input$x,'\n') y=input$y)) + geom_point() and I got  Error:geom_point requires the following missing aesthetics: x and y

Comment: @MrFlick here are some the inputs I am passing                                         
radioButtons(
  "x", 
  h3("X Variable"),
  choices = list("date" = 1),
  selected = "class",
  choiceValues = c("Timestamp.Excel_1900.")
  )
checkboxGroupInput(
  'y', 
  h3("Y Variables"), 
  choiceNames = c("temperature [C]")
  )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to debug your code, you can print the data you are using in the console using `cat`, for example:

```
renderPlot({
   cat('input$x=',input$x,'\n')
   p <- ggplot(Merged_data_frame_hcat, aes_string(x=input$x, y=input$y)) + geom_point()
   print(p)
  
})
```

If you look at the RStudio console, you'll see the value you're passing to `aes_string`.
From your answers in the comments, you'll most probably see in the console:

```
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

Listening on http://127.0.0.1
input$x = 1
```

This is due to the way `selectInput` [works](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/selectInput.html) :

> **choices** : List of values to select from. **If elements of the list are named, then that name --- rather than the value --- is displayed to the user**.

This means that if

```
choices = list('dates'=1)
```

You see `dates` in the `selectInput`and you get `1` in `input$x`.
For further help, as pointed out by @MrFlick in the first comment, you'll need to provide a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/13513328) : discovering & solving a problem mainly through comments isn't efficient.

Comment: I am new to using shiny so I was using a example code for the select input. Would it work if i just remove the 1 . and would the corrections you pointed above still work if there was other x inputs

Comment: I got it to work by removing the 1 and leaving it as                                    radioButtons(
  "x", 
  h3("X Variable"),
  choices = c("date"="Timestamp.Excel_1900."))                                                                    ggplot displayed the data point a bit grouped up. I did some research on plotly and it seems like it helps you zoom in to specific dates. However the same code with plotly is  still not working.